# Java threads and /proc/ directory on linux

Tags: java, proc, thread

I have a Java program that uses a pool of worker threads, that execute the work. These threads are dynamic, so the program creates and removes threads dynamically.
The thread is running while a variable is true:

```
        public void run() {

            while (!exit) {
```

So stopping a thread is setting this variable to false for that thread.

- I can find these thread id directories on `/proc/$pid/task/$tid`.
- The worker threads have a specific name so I can check these in `/proc/$pid/task/$tid/comm`.

However after stopping a thread I can still find the `$tid` subdirectory for about 10 minutes. I also don't see a difference in the `/proc/$pid/task/$tid/status` after stopping a Java thread.

I am a novice in these (RedHat) linux processes/monitoring, but was wondering: is there some way to know "in real time" that a Java worker thread was stopped?